# Solve the Diophantine equation:- $x_1^4+x_2^4+...+x_{14}^4=15999$

Tags: number-theory

Solve the Diophantine equation:-

$x_1^4+x_2^4+...+x_{14}^4=15999$

I unsuccessfully tried to use the concept that every fourth power is of the form $4k$ or $4k+1$. Please help.

Comment: There are no solution. For any integer $x$, we have
$$x^4 \equiv 0 \text{ or } 1 \pmod{16}$$
This implies 
$$15999 \equiv 15 \not\equiv x_1^4 + \cdots + x_{14}^4\pmod{16}$$

Comment: @achillehui if that was an answer I would upvote it ;-)

Comment: @achille hui yeah that is correct.

Comment: @achillehui: Why work with modulo 16? Is that a matter of experience? :)

Comment: Partially a matter of experience, yes. But you're looking for a modulus for which there are very few fourth powers; one way to accomplish this is for the exponent of the group of units to be a small multiple of $4$. So the moduli $5$ and $10$, perhaps $13$, and $16$ are natural ones to try.

Comment: @PranavArora sort of by experience. We know $x^2$ is either a multiple of $4$ or of the form $8k+1$. So there are not too many choices for $x^4$ under modulus $16 = 2^4$. Another hint is $15999$ is very close to $16000$.

Comment: Thank you achillehui and GregMartin! :)

Comment: @achillehui Would you care to write that down as an answer?